# Retrieving ID while having only user_name

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I'm trying to make a private message system.

What I have so far.
- checking if player exists with the name from textbox, if not, error shows up.

Now, I'm trying to insert it to the table. The problem is that the table have 2 colums

```
to_user_id
from_user_id
```

And becasuse I'm using a textbox to enter the name of the user, I dont how to retrieve to_user_id from users table while having only name.

this is my code

```
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connect"].ToString());
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand();
    cmdd.CommandText = "select * from [users]";
    cmdd.Connection = conn;

    SqlDataReader rd = cmdd.ExecuteReader();


    while (rd.Read())
    {
        if (rd[1].ToString() == TextBox_To.Text)
        {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }

    }
    conn.Close();
    if (flag == true)
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "User does not exist";

    }
    else if(flag == false)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connect"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.Connection = con;

            cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO messages (message_title, message_content, to_user_id, from_user_id, message_date) 
                                VALUES (@title, @content, @to, @from, @date)";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", TextBox_Title.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", TextBox_Msg.Text.Replace("\n", "<br/>"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", TextBox_To.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", Session["id"].ToString());




            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

    }
```

Of course I got an error

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'username' to data type int.
```

@edit,

@cordan I tried this

```
DECLARE @user_id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_login=@to ); 
                                    INSERT INTO messages (message_title, message_content, to_user_id, from_user_id, message_date) 
                                    VALUES (@title, @content, @user_id, @from, @date); 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", TextBox_To.Text);
```

got this error

```
 Incorrect syntax near '='.
Must declare the scalar variable "@user_id".
```

Comment: have you considered looking up the user from the users table? i.e. `SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = @username`, then using the result of that query?

Comment: @codran I'm not sure how to put that looked up id to a variable  so I can then use it as   '           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", retrieved_id);'

Comment: SET @user = (SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE user_name = @user_name)

Comment: @Harugawa Either retrieve it in a separate DbCommand beforehand (preferably inside a transaction), or make it a separate statement as part of your INSERT query. e.g. `DECLARE @user_id = (SELECT ... ); INSERT INTO ... VALUES ( ..., @user_id, ...);`

Comment: @cordan check my edited post

Comment: @Harugawa your update just has a very simple syntax error. Learn to google error messges!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit here is a huge NO!!

```
SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand();
cmdd.CommandText = "select * from [users]";
cmdd.Connection = conn;

SqlDataReader rd = cmdd.ExecuteReader();


while (rd.Read())
{
    if (rd[1].ToString() == TextBox_To.Text)
    {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }

}
conn.Close();
```

You are selecting every single user from the users table, just to determine if the one you're trying to find exists.

Aside from the fact that you could almost certainly just add:

```
    if (rd[1].ToString() == TextBox_To.Text)
    {
        foundUserId = (int)rd[0]; // I'm assuming the first column in users is the Id - it probably is
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
```

**DONT DO THAT!!**

---

Instead, you should just be looking for the one username you're interested in

```
SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand();
cmdd.CommandText = "select top 1 Id from [users] where username=@username";
cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",username);
cmdd.Connection = conn;

SqlDataReader rd = cmdd.ExecuteReader();

var userId = 0;
if(rd.Read())
{
    userId = (int)rd[0];
}
conn.Close();
if (userId == 0)
{
    Label1.Visible = true;
    Label1.Text = "User does not exist";
    return;
}
else
   .... // userId holds the users Id
   ...
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", userId);
```

Comment: While you're at it, why top 1? assuming user name should be unique, top 1 is useless. also, why `ExecuteReader` when you can use `ExecuteScalar` and do the entire thing in one sql connection instead of 2?

Comment: Adding onto what Zohar said, if you'r going to show the correct way to do this please safely dispose of your disposables.